# How do i push my 'msg' object into the empty array in this snippet

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So i want middleware to push an obj "msg": "Some message" to my errors array

```
router.post('/register', (req, res)=> {

    let errors = [];
    const { name, email, password, password_ } = req.body;

    //checking
    if(!name || !email || !password || !password_){
        errors.push({ "msg": '1231231243'});
    } 
    if(errors.length > 0){
        res.render('register', {
            errors,
            name,
            email,
            password,
            password_
        });
    } 
    else {
        res.send('PASSS')
    };
```

I expect it to show me that msg or send "PASSS" to my browser once i complete the form.

Comment: please attach a working snippet, so that we can better understand what you've tried and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: what is the behaviour you are seeing?